# ajax webservices

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I am trying to use ajax to call my web services. Already i have deployed my web-service in my virtual machine.

URL:

http://www.lumiin.ch:8080/lumiin-service/lumiin/control/vprospects

**Try this URL with Rest client Jar**

```
Method = GET
Key = accept
value = Application/json

**My Code below** 



     $.ajax({
              type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
              url: "http://www.lumiin.ch:8080/lumiin-service/lumiin/control/vprospects", // Location of the service
              data: "", //Data sent to server                           
              contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
              dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
              processdata: true, //True or False
              success: function (data) {//On Successfull service call

              var result = json.name;
                alert("result===" + result);
               $("#dvAjax").html(result);
            },
            error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
            });

               return false;
        });

    });
```

But I am getting no response from the above code. Please help me out in this.

Regd's
Karthick

Comment: When I visit the URL above, I get an exception indicating that you have multiple annotations for your RPC parameters.  I might guess that you have stale class files in your classpath, causing the framework to pick both up and get confused.

Comment: Change type:"POST" and then try

Comment: Hi jheddings, check this URL  http://88.80.223.163:8080/lumiin-service/lumiin/control/vprospects

Comment: Haseeb Akhtar , After changing to POST method also no response. Any idea ?  Thanks Karthick

Comment: I am still getting an error on the URL:  `Class has two properties of the same name "closed_count"`  Full text of the exception pasted here: http://pastebin.com/qYAg5f7y  (server is returning a 500)  It appears from this message that there is a server configuration problem preventing your `VProspectList` from loading.

Comment: Do you have some console monitor on your browser?Like we have firebug in Mozilla,Try monitoring the AJAX call using that.It may give you some heading.

Comment: http://88.80.223.163:8080/lumiin-service/lumiin/control/vprospects {Try this URL with Rest client Jar it will work} Method - GET; Key - Accept; Value - application/json;

Comment: techie_28 I have installed firebug in Mozilla, while monitoring my console i'm getting [acpp] : LOCAL_COOKIE_STATS_STATS_SITE_IRRELEVANT

Comment: jheddings Try using Rest client jar, Don't hit the URL in your browser it will response with 500 error. Use REST CLIENT Jar.

Comment: techie_28 I am getting the error in my console as:  ReferenceError: json is not defined;   

var result = json.name;

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it has something to do with the `JSONP` requests that `jQuery` does.
May be it is looking for `callback=?`

try adding this

```
$.ajax({
   jsonp :false,
   -- other params here--
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this line :

```
var result = json.name;
```

to this:

```
var result = data.name;
```

and this:

```
 error: ServiceFailed
```

to this:

```
 error: function(){ alert('ServiceFailed');}
```

Try and see if this solves your issue.